# Sometimes printing is completed without printing

Tags: cups, printing, nixos

I have a Brother laser printer DCP-1612W and when I print some PDFs with images the job is flagged as completed even if nothing was printed (but the printer makes some noise).

I'm using brlaser driver.

In cups log I cannot find anything useful.

```
journalctl --follow --unit=cups
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Adding start banner page "none".
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Queued on "Brother" by "dpd-".
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: REQUEST localhost - - "POST /printers/Brother HTTP/1.1" 200 567 Create-Job successful-ok
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] File of type application/postscript queued by "dpd-".
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Adding end banner page "none".
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Started filter /nix/store/0ynxwkwr0vc021y1v0kljjdzp10vgd67-cups-progs/lib/cups/filter/gstopdf (PID 178823)
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Started filter /nix/store/0ynxwkwr0vc021y1v0kljjdzp10vgd67-cups-progs/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 178824)
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Started filter /nix/store/0ynxwkwr0vc021y1v0kljjdzp10vgd67-cups-progs/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 178825)
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Started filter /nix/store/0ynxwkwr0vc021y1v0kljjdzp10vgd67-cups-progs/lib/cups/filter/rastertobrlaser (PID 178826)
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Started backend /nix/store/0ynxwkwr0vc021y1v0kljjdzp10vgd67-cups-progs/lib/cups/backend/ipp (PID 178827)
Dec 06 21:24:31 PereBook cupsd[177160]: REQUEST localhost - - "POST /printers/Brother HTTP/1.1" 200 3542310 Send-Document successful-ok
Dec 06 21:24:32 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:33 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:34 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:35 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:36 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:37 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:38 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:39 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:40 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:41 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
Dec 06 21:24:41 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Brother dpd- 95 [06/Dec/2023:21:24:41 +0100] total 1 1 localhost 2023.pdf A4 one-sided
Dec 06 21:24:41 PereBook cupsd[177160]: [Job 95] Job completed.
Dec 06 21:24:41 PereBook cupsd[177160]: Expiring subscriptions...
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/18cdpsu/sometimes_printing_is_completed_without_printing/kcax1ui/) the problem is that brlaser is not updated. Using the [Owl-Maintain fork](https://github.com/Owl-Maintain/brlaser/) it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is possible to print an empty print job.

In particular, postscript is a "page description language" rather than actual content to be printed, so if a particular postscript file doesn't include a `showpage` command to actually emit a page, it won't generate anything to print.

If I'm reading the log file correctly, you are sending a postscript file to the printer.  If the file either doesn't generate pages or is somehow malformed (or maybe wasn't postscript but the spooler tried to print it as if it was), then there will be nothing to print.

You didn't include any details about the file you are trying to print.
If it is postscript, you can try viewing it with a previewer (such as ghostscript or evince) and see what is in it.  If it is not postscript or is malformed, ghostscript should explain why exactly.  Other programs may hide the error.

If the file is not postscript possibly it is being converted to postscript but not correctly, leaving an empty print job.  (If this is the case, add more detail about the file you are trying to print to your question.)

Comment: As can be read on third line from bottom, the file is a pdf. Although now I see the first applied filter is gstopdf; I don't know why.